# Twitter Bootstrap 3 File Structure Confusion

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded the bootstrap 3 master zip from github (which includes the docu site), and noticed that they are importing the header/footer file into the page/default.html file like you would do in PHP.

For example, this is the code in the home.html file (in docs/_layouts):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
{% include header.html %}
</head>
<body class="bs-docs-home">
<a class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">Skip to main content</a>

<!-- Docs master nav -->
{% include nav/main.html %}

<!-- Page content of course! -->
{{ content }}

{% include footer.html %}
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do the same thing? Are they using Javascript to import the files? I'm on a server that doesn't allow php (college site).

Any help would be appreciated since I'm am still learning and this would make it a lot easier not having to update 20+ html files each time the menu changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap documentation uses the [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) static website build tool.
Jekyll uses the Liquid [templating language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system), which is what interprets the `{% include %}` directives and `{{ }}` expressions. Here are some docs on Liquid:

- http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/
- http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics

The templating doesn't involve JavaScript. The templates are evaluated once, at build time, to produce static HTML files. Jekyll itself is written in the Ruby programming language.

Comment: I think OP has another question after this, "What is a template engine?"